# Use Marlett.ttf as a font with CSS

Tags: css, font-face

I'm working on a web-based GUI, for which I chose to use some graphical elements from Windows. These elements are the ones Windows gets from its own system font named Marlett.ttf : for those of you who aren't familiar with it, Marlett.ttf contains the caracters used in Windows to render multiple GUI details : window operations symbols (cross, dash, squares), scrollbar arrows, and so on.

As I want to achieve my goal without any image and in pure CSS, I figured I'd just use CSS3 @font-face property to make sure I can use Marlett.ttf in my webpages.

None of my trials (calling the local font file, extracting it (which was a pain in the ass because it's a truly well hidden file, I had to use xcopy to get a copy of it from my own Windows !) and calling it as a distant file...) were successful.

I even tried to use cufòn, even if I wouldn't have been satisfied at all with it, but even the cufòn website seems to fail generating a proper .font.js file from that goddamn .ttf : the only result I get from this being an empty  tag, as if cufòn was unable to parse characters from that font. These are perfectly standard though (speaking of indexes, these caracters correspond to digits from 0 to 9 and lowercase letters from a to z).

The marlett.ttf file itself doesn't seem to be specific in any way, as you can check its content with charmap or simply by double-clicking it and using Windows' font preview function. I didn't check it with another OS though...

Does anyone has any clue about what's going wrong here ? Why can't I use that font like any other one, and what can I do about it ? Does the file have "special" properties making it unreadabke by anything but Windows (even if I'd have real trouble believing it), and if it does, would there be any way for me to get rid of it ?

Thanks in advance for your time. Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kRkBa/

Comment: Pretty sure you're not supposed to do this. You can't even purchase/license the font... http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1047

Comment: Aside from the fact you dont have a license to do this, If your prepared to embed a font why not just use a single png sprite image that contains the graphics?

Comment: I think it does have special properties, or rather, a special lack of properties. If you look at Marlett with the Character Map (at least on my machine) it doesn't show any Unicode ranges or codepoints for the glyphs. So it doesn't have any character tables.

Comment: Alex K. : I guess you're right, it could even be lighter. My purpose was to achieve this as a technical "challenge" (I really mean the quotes), since I never tried this kind of thing before.

Mr Lister : you're right too, the info displayed by charmap isn't the same than for just any other font. I didn't really think about it before... Guess it's a kind of protection since this font is licensed as MetalFrog and AlexK. said...

I'm giving up using this font. Thanks for your time and advices !